# Using views in postgresql to enable transparent replacement of backing tables

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

We have a view that aggregates from a backing table.  The idea is to reduce cpu load by using a pre-aggregated table, and to periodically refresh it with the following:

- create new_backing_table (fill it)
- begin
- drop backingtable
- rename new_backingtable to backingtable
- commit

while in production.  The latency caused by the refresh interval is acceptable. Incremental updates are possible but not desirable.

Anyone has a comment on this scheme ?

Comment: Maybe also "create or replace" the view inside the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out  **materialized views**.  This may suit your use case.  It can be used to store query results at creation then refreshed at a later time.

> A materialized view is defined as a table which is actually physically stored on disk, but is really just a view of other database tables. In PostgreSQL, like many database systems, when data is retrieved from a traditional view it is really executing the underlying query or queries that build that view.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: Yes !  Goold idea. Thanks.